# Why can't I fix this deformation with weight painting?

Tags: modeling, animation, weight-painting

My model's tongue / teeth seem to be deforming and sticking when I move my character. I've tried to fix this problem with weight paints, which helped to a certain extent.

I'm still having issues with it however! I don't think I connected the tongue correctly.

Note: the teeth, tongue and body are all part of one object, not separate items.

Any advice on what I can do to eradicate this issue would me much appreciated!

[image: Weight painting issue with face]

Also, this is what it looks like with a rotated head:

[image: blender model rotated head]

The Blender file is here for reference:

[image]

[image: deformed chest and face]

Comment: select the tongue vertices, remove them from all groups, them parent them to the group they are supposed to be part of

Comment: Thank you moonboots. Even if they are all part of the same object?

Comment: yes, just make sure that you've selected the good vertices, but it would make the things simpler if the tongue is a separate mesh (not separate object)

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "parent them to the group they are supposed to be part of"? I'm quite new to Blender so if you could elaborate on that it would be great!

Comment: when you parent With Automatic Weight, it creates a series of vertex groups in the mesh (Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups). These vertex groups will have the same name as the bones and all the vertices will be part of one or another vertex group. Sometimes some vertices are not assigned to the righ vertex group, so select these vertices and in the dropdown menu on the right of the Vertex Groups list (click on the down arrow) choose Remove from All Groups, then select the right vertex group and press Assign

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly - legend. :D

Comment: One more thing - when I now move the hand his entire chest and mouth deform after these changes. Do you know why this is? I've added the picture to the main question.

Comment: you need to make sure that the parenting is correct in Weight Paint mode. Also put the Armature modifier above the Subdivision, it will give better result (I don't know if it will fix your problem though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parent *With Automatic Weight*, it creates a series of vertex groups in the mesh (*Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*). These vertex groups will have the same name as the bones and all the vertices will be part of one or another vertex group. Sometimes some vertices are not assigned to the righ vertex group, so select these vertices and in the dropdown menu on the right of the *Vertex Groups* list (click on the down arrow) choose *Remove from All Groups*, then select the right vertex group and press *Assign*.